Why is the dispatch livewire 3 didnt emit the data
I have a problem where the dispatch didn't do anything. I'm using Livewire v3.5.2. So I have a form for updating the data in my database. The Livewire component to handle the form look like this
public function updateValas()
    {
        $this->validate();

        try {
            Valas::find($this->editingId)->update($this->editingValas);
            $this->closeEditModal();
            session()->flash('message', 'Data Valas berhasil diperbarui.');
            $this->dispatch('refreshValas');  // Menggunakan dispatch untuk update edit
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            session()->flash('error', 'Terjadi kesalahan saat memperbarui data.');
        }
    }

Then, the listeners is from the main component, it look like this,
    protected $listeners = [
        'refreshCounterRates' => 'refreshCounterRates',
        'refreshVideo' => 'refreshVideo',
        'refreshImage' => 'refreshImage',
        'refreshValas' => 'refreshValas',
    ];

    public function refreshValas()
    {
        \Log::info('refreshValas event received');
        $valas = Valas::all()->toArray();
        $totalValas = count($valas);
        $halfCount = ceil($totalValas / 2);

        $this->valasTable1 = array_slice($valas, 0, $halfCount);
        $this->valasTable2 = array_slice($valas, $halfCount);
    }

    public function mount($playlistId)
    {
        $this->playlistId = $playlistId;
        $this->refreshQueue();
        $this->refreshValas();
        $this->refreshCounterRates();
        $this->refreshVideo();
        $this->updateDateTime();
        $this->updateLastUpdateTime();
        $this->refreshImage();
    }


But nothing happen. I already do logging, the event successfully dispatched but nothing received. I try to use instruction from documentation like this,
    #[On('refresh-valas')] 
    public function refreshValas()
    {
        \Log::info('refreshValas event received');
        $valas = Valas::all()->toArray();
        $totalValas = count($valas);
        $halfCount = ceil($totalValas / 2);

        $this->valasTable1 = array_slice($valas, 0, $halfCount);
        $this->valasTable2 = array_slice($valas, $halfCount);
    }

But, the result is the same. Its not changing. Anyone can help this?
I hope I find the problem to see what's wrong
UPDATE
This is the form that will trigger the updateValas() function
<!-- Edit Modal -->
    <div x-show="$wire.isEditModalOpen" class="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto" aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
            <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" aria-hidden="true"></div>
            <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>
            <div class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full">
                <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                    <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900" id="modal-title">Edit Valas</h3>
                    <div class="mt-2">
                        <label for="buy" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-1">Kode ISO Valas</label>
                        <input wire:model="editingValas.kode_iso_valas" class="block w-full pl-3 pr-4 py-3 rounded-md bg-gray-50 border-transparent focus:border-blue-500 focus:bg-white focus:ring-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out shadow-sm hover:shadow-md" type="text" placeholder="Kode ISO Valas">
                        @error('editingValas.kode_iso_valas') <span class="text-red-500 text-sm">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                        <label for="buy" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-1">Kode Valas</label>
                            <input wire:model="editingValas.kode_valas" class="block w-full pl-3 pr-4 py-3 rounded-md bg-gray-50 border-transparent focus:border-blue-500 focus:bg-white focus:ring-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out shadow-sm hover:shadow-md" type="text" placeholder="Kode Valas">
                            @error('editingValas.kode_valas') <span class="text-red-500 text-sm">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                        <label for="buy" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-1 mt-3">Beli</label>
                        <div class="relative">
                            <span class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 flex items-center ">
                                Rp
                            </span>
                            <input wire:model="editingValas.beli" class="block w-full pl-10 pr-4 py-3 rounded-md bg-gray-50 border-transparent focus:border-blue-500 focus:bg-white focus:ring-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out shadow-sm hover:shadow-md" type="text" placeholder="Beli">
                            @error('editingValas.beli') <span class="text-red-500 text-sm">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                        </div>
                        <label for="sell" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-1 mt-3">Jual</label>
                        <div class="relative">
                            <span class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 flex items-center ">
                                Rp
                            </span>
                            <input wire:model="editingValas.jual" class="block w-full pl-10 pr-4 py-3 rounded-md bg-gray-50 border-transparent focus:border-blue-500 focus:bg-white focus:ring-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out shadow-sm hover:shadow-md" type="text" placeholder="Jual">
                            @error('editingValas.jual') <span class="text-red-500 text-sm">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
                    <button wire:click="updateValas" type="button" class="w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-blue-600 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm">
                        Update
                    </button>
                    <button wire:click="closeEditModal" type="button" class="mt-3 w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-white text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm">
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


It would be useful to see the views to also understand how they are interconnected. How is the updateValas() method invoked?

@TUPKAP I added new additional information about how the updateValas() method invoked

By doing a test and assuming that the component that calls updateValas() is contained in the one that receives the event, everything works correctly for me. Have you tried writing something to a log in the method triggered by the event? Obviously, in order for the mechanism to work, the components must both be present on the same page
